# C++: Why am I getting this segmentation fault (possibly occuring before main?)

Tags: c++

I just finished most (I thought!) of my debugging, and my code now compiles without any errors. However, when I try to run it, it returns a segfault even before the first line of main! I'm wondering if it's maybe a memory issue, having to do with the strings in my struct definition, but I haven't even initialized them yet so I don't know how that would work.
Another thing I thought is maybe I need to use the new operator when I'm setting my strings, but my book  declares strings the same way I do, as far as I can tell (although theirs aren't a part of structs...)

Anyway, here's my code! We're supposed to crack some (presumably really awful) passwords that all use the same salt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <crypt.h>
using namespace std;

/* Read in a large, standard dictionary.
   Encrypt each word in the dictionary using the crypt() function
   Read in the password file and check each user's password to see
   whether it matches one of the dictionary entries
   Output the passwords for all of the accounts you have
   broken. */
struct ListNode{
  string user;
  string salt;
  string encrypted;
  string password;
  ListNode* next;
};


int main(){

  cout<<"Hello world\n\n";
  /* Initializes singly linked list to hold user data */
  ListNode *root;
  ListNode *conductor;
  root = new ListNode;
  conductor = root;

  cout<<"After initializing list\n\n";
  string temp;

  //creates and opens filestream to password file
  ifstream psswdFile ("simplepsswd.txt");

  if(psswdFile.is_open()){
    //we assume there is at least one line, and initialize the head of
    //the list
    std::getline(psswdFile, conductor->user, ':');
    std::getline(psswdFile, conductor->salt, ':');
    std::getline(psswdFile, conductor->encrypted);
    //create first node
    //while there's more lines (store username in temp so we can
    //check)
    cout<< "Before password loop\n\n";
    while(std::getline(psswdFile, temp, ':')){
      //create next node
      conductor->next = new ListNode;
      conductor = conductor->next;
      conductor->next = NULL;
      //set data fields
      conductor->user = temp;
      //I know we don't NEED to store the salt but what if you decided
      //you wanted it later
      std::getline(psswdFile, conductor->salt, ':');
      std::getline(psswdFile, conductor->encrypted);
    }
  }

  //open the dictionary file
  ifstream dicFile("/usr/share/myspell/en_US.dic");
  string dicEntry;
  string dicEncrypted;

  if(dicFile.is_open()){
    int loc;
    //loop through words in dictionary
    cout<<"Before dictionary loop\n\n";
    while(std::getline(dicFile, dicEntry)){
      //check for weird flags and whatever.
      int loc = dicEntry.find('/');
      if(loc > 0){
    //if they're there, get rid of them!
    dicEntry.resize(loc);
      }
      //convert the entry to a c-string so we can use crypt on it
      char* cString;
      strcpy(cString, dicEntry.c_str());
      cString = crypt(cString, "AB");
      dicEncrypted = cString;
      //loop through the list comparing to encrypted passwords
      conductor = root;
      if(conductor->encrypted == dicEncrypted){
    conductor->password = dicEntry;
      }
      //password could occur more than once!
      while(conductor->next != NULL){
    conductor = conductor->next;
    if(conductor->encrypted == dicEncrypted){
      conductor->password = dicEntry;
    }
      }
    }
  }
  cout<<"Before print loop\n\n";
  conductor = root;
  if(conductor->password != ""){
    cout << "User " << conductor->user << "'s password is " << conductor->password << "\n\n";
  }
  while(conductor->next != NULL){
    conductor = conductor->next;
    if(conductor->password != ""){
      cout<<"User " << conductor->user << "'s password is " << conductor->password <<"\n\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

OK so I tried some things that are in the comments, it seems like I'm getting a segfault as soon as i create my first ListNode!

Comment: little jingle song "valgrind is the answeeeeer"♪

Comment: try using `std::endl` instead of '\n' for your strings, `std::endl` flushes the output stream after inserting the '\n' character into the stream.

Comment: I googled "valgrind", but my program needs to run on my school's computers so I'm not sure how I would install it. Of course I haven't done much with those computers so I don't know for sure what's possible.

Comment: How have you determinded, that the program crashes before the first line of main? If you used a debugger, what is the output / stacktrace. Aside from this: why do you use a singly linked list and especially, why do you implmenet it yourself?

Comment: Also just tried switching to std::endl, didn't help :c
I didn't use a debugger, usually printing out things works fine for me, and I am really rusty with Unix. 
I used a singly linked list because I figured I wouldn't know how many lines there were in the file I was reading from so I couldn't use an array, and it seemed silly to read it through twice to count the lines.
I implemented it myself because that's what we did in class last year, I thought that's what you're supposed to do?

Comment: At least on other line, where your program will brobybly crash is `strcpy(cString, dicEntry.c_str());` as cString doesn't point to any allocated space of memory

Comment: Well the STL library provides std::list which is an implementation of a doubly linked list, but what you usually want to use is std::vector. If you want to learn about c++, you should definitively learn about the functions and containers in the STL, but for learning purposes it is ok, if you try implement them yourself. But back to your problem: If you don't have a debugger, then you should probably start by commenting out all lines in the main function and then on by one adding the individual blocks, so you can see where the problem comes from.

Comment: What is the best way to allocate memory to that variable, then? I am not sure how I would assign it a size, since each entry could be different. I thought that using strcpy would initialize it, but I'm not surprised that I'm wrong.

Comment: Seems like "ListNode *root" is the issue

Answer (score 0):

One issue right away is that you are writing to an uninitialized pointer:

```
  //convert the entry to a c-string so we can use crypt on it
  char* cString;
  strcpy(cString, dicEntry.c_str());
  cString = crypt(cString, "AB");
  dicEncrypted = cString;
```

The `cString` is an uninitialized pointer pointing to who-knows-where.  Then you write characters to this memory address with the `strcpy` function.  This is undefined behavior, and most likely, a segmentation fault.

You have to allocate memory so that `strcpy` has room to write the string (plus the terminating NULL).

```
  char cString[100]; // or whatever number is large enough
  strcpy(cString, dicEntry.c_str());
  cString = crypt(cString, "AB");
  dicEncrypted = cString;
```

But even this is not safe, since `100` may not be enough room.  You need to post the `crypt` function to get you a more robust answer.